# Flask SQL Alchemy NoReferencedTableError

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Problem with creating relationship between two SQLAlchemy Databases in separate files.

**Project/Main/models.py**

```
from Blog.Main import db, app
from flask_login import UserMixin, login_manager

@app.login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return Users.query.get(int(user_id))

class Users(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    email_updates = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)

    tasks = db.relationship("Todo", backref="user")
```

**Project/Task_Manager/task_manager.py**

```
class Todo(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = "taskmanagerdb"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)
 
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Task %i' % self.id
```

**Error**

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'todo.user_id' could not find table 'users' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'

Comment: There's a difference between your `Users` class in Python and your `users` table in SQL. Try `db.ForeignKey('Users.id'...)` - note the capitalization.

Comment: Show us the actual command that produced this error.

Comment: In models.py

File "/workspaces/Blog-Project/Blog/Main/models.py", line 6, in load_user
    return Users.query.get(int(user_id))

Comment: It's not supported foreign key with different databases